# Authentication issue in MVC application using angularJs client side routing

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC application where I am using angularjs routing for and here is example of routing

```
angularFormsApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.caseInsensitiveMatch = true;
        $routeProvider
            .when("/account/index", {
                title: "Login",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL+"app/Login/loginTemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .when("/forgotpasswordform", {
                title: "Forgot Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/Login/forgotPasswordFormtemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .when("/forgotpasswordconfirmation", {
                title: "Forgot Password",
                templateUrl: window.serverURL + "app/Login/forgotPassConfirmationTemplate.html",
                controller: "loginController"
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/account/index" });

    }]);
```

Now when I open default login url . eg. `http://localhost/#/account/index` after logging in application goes to some other page.

Now If I again open same url `http://localhost/#/account/index` though I am already being logged into(Authenticated )... Trick I am using to check whether user is verified is on load of angular controller I am doing a ajax call to check whether session is active and valid then redirecting user to some other page.

But problem is this process is taking few seconds and in mean while page is being loaded then its being redirected.

here is code of login controller

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("account/index") !== -1) {
        $scope.load();
    }

   $scope.load = function () {

        var onAuthComplete = function (data) {
            window.hideProgress();
            if (data === "redirect") {
                //window.location.href = baseurl;
                $window.location.assign(baseurl);
            }
            else if (data !== "") {
                window.location.href = baseurl + "Listing";
            }
        };


        window.showProgress();
        DataService.checkAuthentication()
            .then(onAuthComplete, onServerError);
    };
```

authentication method and mvc controller is as follows

```
var checkAuthentication = function () {
                return $http.post(baseurl + "Account/CheckAuthentication/")
                                .then(function (response) {
                                    return response.data;
                                });
            }
```

and controller code is as below

```
   [HttpPost]
            [AllowAnonymous]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryHeader]
            public ActionResult CheckAuthentication()
            {
                if (Session["UserRole"] != null && Session["UserFullName"] != null && Session["UserName"] != null &&
                    Session["UserType"] != null && Session["EmployeeId"] != null && Session["AuthToken"] != null)
                {
                    if (Request.Cookies["AuthToken"] != null)
                    {
                        var value = Request.Cookies["AuthToken"].Value;

                        if ((string)Session["AuthToken"] == value)
                        {
                            return GetJsonContentResult("Authenticationed");
                        }
                        AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
                        SessionService.Logout();
                        return GetJsonContentResult("redirect");
                    }
                    AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
                    SessionService.Logout();
                    return GetJsonContentResult("redirect");
                }
                return GetJsonContentResult("");
            }
```

Is there any other way to do it in better way as its taking some time and in mean time template is being loaded.

Comment: Can u show a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: Problem is after login when again I open login page.. so it will check for authentication by making controller a call.. so this time is taking few seconds... so in mean time login template is being loaded... then its being redirected...

Comment: And which part is your main problem? what is your desired behavior?

Comment: My desired behavior is When user is logged in and after log in he user again open login url.. then request should be validated from server side rather than first loading template and processing logic wriiten inside angularjs controller then redirect